# Node.js require fail when outside of app.js

Tags: node.js, path, require

I am trying to load a custom module `./routes/exchange.js` from another module `./routes/socketRouter.js`. It throws

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module './routes/exchange'
```

The same call `require('./routes/exchange)` done from app.js (in the root directory) is successfull!

Is there a limitation that prevent calling require somewhere else than in the app.js?

I already tried many different path such as:
`require('./routes/exchange.js')`, `require('exchange')`, `require('exchange.js')`

Thanks!

Comment: you want `require('./exchange')` because it's in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require('./exchange')
```

That will load a module in the same directory as the source module you're requiring from.

`require('exchange')` would only load the module if it was in the base `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0):

When requiring from customer modules and files, you give the relative path to the file. So with the follow structures

```
./my-app
  app.js
  routes/
    exchange.js
    socketRouter.js
  some-folder/
    some-file.js
```

Now when including `exchange.js` from `app.js`, you'd use `require('./routes/exchange')` When including it from socketRouter.js you'd it's in the same folder, so `require('./excahnge')`.

Just for clarity, when wanting to include exchange.js from some-file.js, you'd reference it as `require('../routes/exchnage')`

(Note, the .js extension is optional when calling it via require, if exchange was a folder, then it would load the index.js file from that folder see http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules and http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules)

Comment: Thank you all! It taugh that the dot was meaning the root path, not the current path!